# Can Varnish 4.x be used on Ubuntu 12.04?

Tags: ubuntu-12.04, varnish

I am quite new to Varnish. The legacy systems at my company use Varnish 3.0.6 running on Ubuntu 12.04. Recently, we have a requirement of upgrading Varnish from 3.x to 4.x and thereby changing the vcl per the rules mentioned here https://www.varnish-cache.org/docs/4.0/whats-new/upgrading.html. However, the prime concern is whether Varnish 4.x will run on Ubuntu 12.04.

As per the Varnish documentation here https://www.varnish-cache.org/releases/install_ubuntu.html, it says Varnish 4.1 can be used on Ubuntu 14.04. But can the same be used on Ubuntu 12.04?

Comment: similar question [Varnish 4 on 12.04](http://askubuntu.com/questions/520850/varnish-4-on-12-04) on [askubuntu](http://askubuntu.com/)